# Is there any way to set priority in reactive functions in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with 2 reactive functions. The thing is, I need one of them to execute before the second one. Here is the code:

```
    sumItemsValues <- reactive({
      actualData <- switch (input$sumTabs,
                            area = sumAreaValues(),
                            kg = sumKgValues(),
                            yield = sumYieldValues(),
                            profits = sumProfitsValues(),
                            price = sumPriceValues(),
                            profitability = sumProfitabilityValues()
      )
    })
    
    sumValues <- reactive({
        actualData <- switch (input$sumTabs,
                            area = areaSum(),
                            kg = kgSum(),
                            yield = yieldSum(),
                            profits = profitsSum(),
                            price = priceSum(),
                            profitability = profitabilitySum()
        )
    })
```

Between this 2 functions, there are more functions, and when I run the app and switch across the tabs for a short period of time I see an error, but it disappears fastly. The error is because It tries to execute first the second function, and the second function requires that first function is executed. Thanks for yout time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `req` in the second function :

```
 sumItemsValues <- reactive({
      switch (input$sumTabs,
              area = sumAreaValues(),
              kg = sumKgValues(),
              yield = sumYieldValues(),
              profits = sumProfitsValues(),
              price = sumPriceValues(),
              profitability = sumProfitabilityValues()
      )
    })
    
    sumValues <- reactive({
        req(sumItemsValues())
        switch (input$sumTabs,
                area = areaSum(),
                kg = kgSum(),
                yield = yieldSum(),
                profits = profitsSum(),
                price = priceSum(),
                profitability = profitabilitySum()
        )
    })
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `req(sumItemsValues())`? Also, inside the `reactive` statements why use assignment to `actualData`?

Comment: @Valeri thanks for your feedback, I was too fast on this one. Yes, it's `req(sumItemsValues())`, and yes I copied the original post but sumValues would output nothing with the assignment only. I corrected the post.

Comment: @Waldi Assignment does in fact return ouput, just silently. That's why `x <- y <- 2` works

Comment: @SmokeyShakers, not as output of a function : try `f <- function(){a <- 1}; f()`

Comment: @Waldi You are incorrect. `f()` is returning a value silently. After your code try, `x <- f()` then `x` in the console

Comment: @SmokeyShakers, thanks, you're right, there's always something to remember or to learn in R!  In the situation above however, the internal assignement seems useless.

Comment: @Waldi Completely agree

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using reactive conductors (`reactive`), you can use reactive values and `observeEvent`, which has a `priority` option:

```
sumItemsValues <- reactiveVal(NULL)
sumValues <- reactiveVal(NULL)

observeEvent(input$sumTabs, {
  actualData <- switch(
    input$sumTabs,
    area = sumAreaValues(),
    kg = sumKgValues(),
    yield = sumYieldValues(),
    profits = sumProfitsValues(),
    price = sumPriceValues(),
    profitability = sumProfitabilityValues()
  )
  sumItemsValues(actualData)
}, priority = 2)

observeEvent(input$sumTabs, {
  actualData <- switch(
    input$sumTabs,
    area = areaSum(),
    kg = kgSum(),
    yield = yieldSum(),
    profits = profitsSum(),
    price = priceSum(),
    profitability = profitabilitySum()
  )
  sumValues(actualData)
}, priority = 1)
```